# Extract information from webpage

Tags: import, web-access

If you browse [this page for instance](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01665363), you'll notice at the bottom in gray, a line with

*Contributor:* *Name < email >*

Certainly for security reasons, the email does not appear in the source code. Instead, one can see `decryptMail("puveng.nyrknaqer@tznvy.pbz", "link5a34220e387d1", "")`. For that reason, *Mathematica* cannot get the email address from `Import["https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-..."]`. I was wondering if it was possible to manage another way: in the end, a human can read the email address (either directly, or by using an page inspector), so there must be a way for *MMA* to get it. Question: how?

I tried using `GUIScreenShot` and then `TextRecognize`; it works provided the resolution is good enough, but it is not very robust (the position depends on the length of the text above, what if the page takes time loading, etc.).

Comment: See WebUnit from Arnold Buzing. That could do it.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by b3m2a1, [`WebUnit`](https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/WebUnit) does the job.

```
StartWebSession[]
OpenWebPage["https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01665363"]
str = GetPageHtml[]
```

Then it suffices to get the info from `str`, typically with something like

```
StringCases[str, Shortest["mailto:" ~~ x__ ~~ "\""] -> x]
```

Comment: Might be worth doing a Q/A on how to fix `WebUnit` for Linux based on what you put in chat and then linking to that here.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes but that's not something general, it depends on the distribution, its version, etc. Also my problem was more due to chromedriver than `WebUnit`. I'll try on another PC and will write a Q/A if relevant.